# Drawing path with google direction api

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3

[image]

I am trying to draw path between multiple places with google direction api but the problem is when I zoom the map the path is not drawn correctly.

I am hitting this api and drawing the path with 'overview_polyline' points from the response of the JSON.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=(startLocationLat),(startLocationLong)&destination=(endLocationLat),(endLocationLong)&waypoints=(self.wayPointBetweenLocations)&key=AIzaSyCK0dxRGRlFqM84SUM3zbVQAdbXEXtN-x0&mode=driving

```
let polygon = GMSPolygon()
polygon.path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: "\(self.overview_points)")
```

Please help me with this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `GMSPolyline` instead of `GMSPolygon` to draw a path.

**Example**:

```
    let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: "\(self.overview_points)")
    let directionPolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    directionPolyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    directionPolyline.strokeWidth = 3
    directionPolyline.map = self.mapView
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Google Maps Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro) part [Snap to Roads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) for points from the response of the JSON.